# Bolt DB Connection Failing AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bolt-cms

I've setup a local instance of bolt using config_local.yml and everything works great.

I've configured my AWS dev environment with config.yml but my EC2 instance can't connect to the DB using bolt (it works just fine if I mysql to the RDS database from the EC2 instance running bolt).

```
# app/config/config.yml
database:
  driver: mysql
  databasename: theDatabaseName
  username: theUserName
  password: thePassword
  hostname: myRDSInstance.myRDSHost.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
  port: 3306
```

I'm 100% sure the credentials are correct (I tested it from the EC2 instance using mysql and it works perfectly.)

I've enable debugging in bolt but bolt-debug.log doesn't get created in app/cache (per the documentation in the config file).

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I've tried recreating an instance of elastic beanstalk.

Comment: I tested this from my localhost host to the AWS RDS instance. I found the location in src/Application.php and did a var_dump on the exception.

An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'theUserName'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Ok... so the stack trace on the EB shows that the connection string is: `mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=ebdb;charset=utf8;` which makes me realize I'm a retard... I put hostname: (instead of host:) in the config... and now I just feel stupid - hehe

Answer (score 0):

I have got exactly the same issue!

My problem was an access issue from my RDS.
Make sure your RDS instance shares the same security group than your web instance